# "writeToFile:atomically:" Fails on File with Certain ACL

Tags: cocoa, serialization, plist, acl, hfs+

If I have a writable file with an ACL-rule of `deny delete`, any `[plistableObject writeFoFile:undeletableFile atomically:YES]` call returns `NO`, whereas non-atomic writes succeed.

I know, that the atomic write means that a temporary file is written and — if written successfully — eventually renamed. This particular implication of it *feels odd*, though.
So I wonder, is this due to...

1. lack of a direct 'rename' in HFS+,
2. a deficiency in the implementation of `-[NS(Array|Dictionary|Data|String) writeToFile:atomically:]` or
3. a deficiency in the implementation of ACLs in Mac OS X?

Thanks in Advance

Daniel

---

**Original question:**
I've found this odd behavior the other day on a Mac I restored from a backup:
Most applications were unable to persist their preferences — especially Mail.app which warned with an error message, suggesting that it was unable to write to `~/Library/Preferences`.

Digging deeper, I found that — somehow — most plists had an ACL with the directive `group:everyone deny delete` in place; ditching this rule saved the day.

I suspected `NSArray|NSDictionary|NSWhatHaveYou`'s `writeToFile:atomically:` to be responsible* for this behavior and — sure enough — the test-tool I wrote only succeeds when passed `NO` as the second argument if the file exists and has such an ACL in place...

(* where by "responsible" I only mean the not-writing-part; the ACL situation was something else entirely)

So I wonder:

Is this a bug or a feature?

While — technically — this method writes a file and upon completion renames it, from a user perspective it is not deleting anything...

*If* it's a bug:
Should it be filed against NSArray and friends or against the implementation of ACLs?

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Cheers

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging in the [HFS source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.0.2/bsd/hfs/) I've come to the conclusion that there is no such thing as a filesystem-native `rename` function in Mac OS.

Instead, it is implemented as (pseudocode)

```
link!
successful:
   return 0
// otherwise
unlink!
successful:
  link!
  return error_code
// otherwise
return error_code
```

So this behavior is to be expected :-(

That said, I don't know enough about either filesystems or low-level programming to decide whether the creation of a native `rename` would be worth the hassle implementing it.

I strongly *feel* it would be the right thing to do so, but...

---

**Edit**

As [jfortman pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662115/is-an-atomic-rename-possible-in-mac-vfs-hfs/5395843#5395843), an atomic rename would actually be possible and pretty straight-forward through use of the following sequence:

1. write to tempfile
2. `exchangedata( path_to_tempfile, path_to_destination_file, options )` (by the way: the [manpage states](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man2/exchangedata.2.html) that this function is around since Darwin 1.3.1/Mac OS X 10.0...)
3. delete tempfile