# Is an atomic-rename possible in Mac VFS/HFS+?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, darwin, vfs, hfs+

With support for ACLs in Mac OS X, there is a way to declare a file as writeable but non-deletable.

This poses a problem with atomic writes, since the [current implementation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.9.26/bsd/vfs/vfs_syscalls.c) of `rename` in VFS `delete`s a pre-existing target. If you have an existing file, which you have write privileges on, it is possible to be *unable* to atomically write to:
Simply attach an ACL that states `deny delete` and an atomic write (like implemented by various Cocoa APIs — e.g. [NSArray's `writeToFile:atomically:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a)) will fail, while a non-atomic write will happily succeed.

Since my understanding of low-level C code is fairly limited:
Is an alternative implementation feasible with only minor (insert your favorite definition of "minor") headaches?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A viable alternative would seem to create the file in a temporary directory, then call `exchangedata` on both files. HFS exports the `VOL_CAP_INT_EXCHANGEDATA` attribute, so that should work. The relevant checks in vfs_syscalls.c indicate that only read and write permissions are necessary for the call to succeed.